# How can cmocka be used to mock functions using --wrap within shared libraries?

Tags: c, unit-testing, linker, shared-libraries, cmocka

I'm using cmocka to unit test a large code base written in C. I'd like unit tests to run at a library level, but I'm having issues mocking functions when compiled in a shared library. I believe the shared library is the issue because I can successfully mock the same code using `--wrap` linker flag when not part of a shared library. For the same `SOURCE_FILE`, here are my two different methods of compiling. For reference, I'm trying to mock the C Standard Library function `strcmp`.

Compilation steps resulting in a successfully mocked `strcmp`:

```
gcc -std=c99 -c SOURCE_FILE.c -o OBJECT_FILE.o
gcc -Wl,-rpath=cmocka/build/src,--wrap=strcmp -Icmocka/include TEST_FILE.c -Lcmocka/build/src -lcmocka OBJECT_FILE.o -o my_test
./my_test
```

Compilation steps for creating a shared library and then testing. An error is thrown executing `my_test` demonstrating unsuccessful mocking of `strcmp`:

```
gcc -std=c99 -fpic -c SOURCE_FILE.c -o OBJECT_FILE.o
gcc -shared OBJECT_FILE.o -o lMY_LIBRARY.so 
gcc -Wl,-rpath=cmocka/build/src,-rpath={path to current dir},--wrap=strcmp -Icmocka/include TEST_FILE.c -L/home/{path to current dir} -Lcmocka/build/src  -lMY_LIBRARY -lcmocka -o my_test 
./my_test
```

for reference this is the error I'm seeing:

```
[  ERROR   ] --- __wrap_strcmp() has remaining non-returned values.
TEST_FILE.c:28: note: remaining item was declared here
__wrap_strcmp.x parameter still has values that haven't been checked.
```

This cmocka error is thrown whenever you're trying to use cmocka `will_return`, but the function wrapping did not occur. I'm trying to figure out why the small step of creating a shared object prevents the gcc linker from wrapping a function call.

I can't find any information on stack overflow or elsewhere regarding use of cmocka on shared objects. Would appreciate any ideas, suggestions, or explainations of why this does not work. I know that `--wrap` does not work when the caller and callee are defined in the same file. Is that what's causing a problem here?

Comment: Did you generate map files for the library and the test program? You might have some insight on the symbols.

Comment: Anyway, please consider to provide a [example] for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you try to add another object file with the function to be mocked? The linker resolves only unresolved references, so if you put this object file before the library in the command line, the library's version will be ignored.

Comment: > This cmocka error is thrown whenever you're trying to use cmocka will_return, but the function wrapping did not occur.

Am not sure about this assumption: I get the exact same error not when the function wrapping did not occur but when I used `will_return` but the mocked function was not reached. Can you please confirm what could be going on?